# How do I get the MySQL affected rows using the Magento resource?

Tags: database, magento-1

```
$conn  = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$sql = "UPDATE ...";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

How do I get the number of affected rows - i.e. `mysql_affected_rows();`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the `$conn->query()` you could use `$conn->update()`. This takes the following parameters:

1. The table that you want to update,
2. An array of column value pairs,
3. The where clause of your statement

It will return the number of affected rows. This is also true for the `delete` and different `insert` functions. You can find the basics of the functions under `Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface`. Or for a good example have a look at `decrementProducts` in `Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Tag`

**EDIT**

If you want to perform an insert on duplicate key update then use the function `insertOnDuplicate`. This takes the following parameters:

1. The table that you want to insert into,
2. An array of column value pairs,
3. An array of columns to update,

A good example of this can be found in the `saveSelectionPrice` function under `Mage_Bundle_Model_Resource_Selection`

Comment: what would I use for an "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"

Comment: There is an insertOnDuplicate function. But the parameters due vary from the normal insert

Comment: @sdfor I have updated my answer to include information about the insertOnDuplicate function

Answer (score 2):

Try with this.

```
  <?php
    $sql = "UPDATE ...";
    $result = $read->fetchAll($sql);
    $total_rows = count($result);
    ?>
```